# Dealing with missing elements in Scala/Spark class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following file in Hadoop

```
val dataset=sc.textFile("/user/hue/mycompanies1.csv")
```

It looks like this

```
CS,84,Jimmys Bistro, Jimmys
CS,90,Pauls Fish
CS,100, Happy Hardware
```

My scala/Spark code looks like:

```
case class Company (
 record_type: String, 
 company_num: Integer, 
 company_name: String;, 
 nickname: String
)

val company = dataset.map(k=>k.split(",")).map(
    k => Company(k(0).trim, k(1).toInt, k(2).trim, k(3).trim)

company.toDF().registerTempTable("company_table4")
```

When i try to access company RDD after i get a nullpointerexception because of the missing nickname value in the data. How do i deal with this gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the nickname is optional, I would change the case class to reflect that, then use one of various ways to optionally obtain the index-3 element, eg:

```
case class Company (
 record_type: String, 
 company_num: Integer, 
 company_name: String, 
 nickname: Option[String]
)

val company = dataset.map(k=>k.split(",")).map(
    k => Company(k(0).trim, k(1).toInt, k(2).trim, k.drop(3).headOption.map(_.trim))
```